# How to pass system stats to syslog

Tags: centos7, rsyslog

I want to pass system stats, especially CPU usage to rsyslog. Can somebody help me on this?

Can we use logger tool to achieve this task?

Thank you
Luke

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can  use [logger](https://linux.die.net/man/1/logger) command to write anything to syslog.

You can write simple script that will send to syslog any data you need.
There is nice [guide](https://urbanautomaton.com/blog/2014/09/09/redirecting-bash-script-output-to-syslog/).

But I believe monitoring system like zabbix will be more functional.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like [snap](https://github.com/intelsdi-x/snap) would do the trick here.